# cron task not working in centos

Tags: php, logging, cron, centos

I have an unknown problem like cron task is not running at all.. I have checked the cron status

# service crond status

crond (pid  30949) is running...

But task is not running, check my crontab list below

```
# crontab -l
```

* * * * * echo -e "\aBEEEP\n"

*/1 * * * * echo -e "\aBEEEP\n"

I added this, to check task is running or not. What is the issue, may be permission ??

No update in /var/log/cron

Thanks in advnace..

Answer (score 0):

Where do you expect the echo output? Your terminal is not connected to this process.

to test if cron is working try, e.g.:

```
* * * * * touch /root/crontest
```

File will be created after 1 minute then.